# Get monthly counts on multiple dates

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table that looks like this

| id | date registered | date cancelled |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-03-02 |
| 2 | 2021-01-05 | 2021-01-21 |
| 3 | 2021-02-04 | 2021-02-25 |
| 4 | 2021-02-16 | 2021-03-26 |

How do I generate a query in mysql that will give me counts of cancelled and registered for each month.
I can do it for just one of the dates but don't know how to combine for both dates.
For eg for a single date I would do this.

```
SELECT date_format(`users`.`dateregistered`,_utf8'%Y-%m') AS `DateREegistered`, count(0) AS `Registration Count` 
FROM `users` 
GROUP BY date_format(`users`.`dateregistered`,_utf8'%Y-%m')
```

But I want something like this

| Date | Registered Count | Cancelled Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01 | 2 | 1 |
| 2021-02 | 2 | 1 |
| 2021-03 | 0 | 2 |

Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can join the distinct months appearing in `date registered` and `date registered` to the table and use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT t.Date,
       SUM(t.Date = date_format(dateregistered, '%Y-%m')) `Registered Count`, 
       SUM(t.Date = date_format(datecancelled, '%Y-%m')) `Cancelled Count`
FROM (
  SELECT date_format(dateregistered, '%Y-%m') Date FROM users
  UNION
  SELECT date_format(datecancelled, '%Y-%m') FROM users
) t INNER JOIN users u
ON t.Date IN (date_format(dateregistered, '%Y-%m'), date_format(datecancelled, '%Y-%m'))
GROUP BY t.Date
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=db5df838599a95b3d1bde6f9579ea9c4).
Results:

| Date | Registered Count | Cancelled Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01 | 2 | 1 |
| 2021-02 | 2 | 1 |
| 2021-03 | 0 | 2 |